# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type. param-index=4 param-type=dict', 'HY105'

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I want to push the data frame to the azure sql server using Python. I have installed SQL odbc driver but suddenly I geterror:sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=4 param-type=dict', 'HY105'

```
 def get_data(): 
    data = res.read() 
    data=json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
    #print(data)
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)
    # #df=df.to_csv('my_data.csv', index=False)
    print(df)

    #return df
    TABLE = 'acc_assets_stocktaking'
    connectionstring = 'mssql+pyodbc://{uid}:{password}@{server}:1433/{database}?driver={driver}'.format(
            uid=AZUREUID,
            password=AZUREPWD,
            server=AZURESRV,
            database=AZUREDB,
            driver=DRIVER.replace(' ', '+'))
    engn = create_engine(connectionstring)
    df.to_sql(TABLE, engn, if_exists='append')
    return df
```

Comment: What is the name of the fourth column in your DataFrame (`print(df.columns[3])`), and what is the data type of the column with that name in the database table (e.g., `nvarchar(max)`, `int`, etc.)?